# TCL: Check file existence by SHELL environment variable

Tags: tcl

I have a shell environment variable `PATH_TO_DIR` and I want to check in TCL script that the file `$PATH_TO_DIR/target.txt` exists.

My current solution is:

```
catch {exec /usr/local/bin/tcsh -c "echo  $PATH_TO_DIR/target.txt" } result

if {![file exists $result]} {
  puts "ERROR: the file $result is not exists"
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way.
How can I solve it only with TCL commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set path_to_dir $::env(PATH_TO_DIR)
set file_name [file join $path_to_dir "target.txt"]
set native_file_name [file nativename $file_name]
if {![file exists $native_file_name]} {
  puts "ERROR: the file $native_file_name does not exist"
}
```

Comment: The file nativename is handy if you're doing any exec calls or platform-specific stuff with the file. But in this case it's not strictly needed.

Comment: +1. More description about the file command here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl25.html

Comment: Brian, thanks for the solution but it is the simpliest one.
What happen if I read lines from a file and one of lines contain string with environment variable that I don't know what it is exactly but I can put it into some local variable.

In this case 
_exec_ _/usr/local/bin/tcsh_ _-c_ "_echo_  _$local_variable/target.txt_"

still work for me , but it also still not elegant.

P.S. I understood that my main question was not forlulated well. Sorry about this.

Comment: Hi, that's no problem. I don't really understand your new question. Maybe if you start a new question and explain it more deeply?

Comment: Hello Brian,
The link to updated question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225508/tcl-check-file-existance-by-shell-environment-variable-another-one