# TCL: Check file existance by SHELL environment variable (another one)

Tags: tcl

I have a file contain lines with path to the files. Sometimes a path contain SHELL environment variable and I want to check the file existence.
The following is my solution:

```
set fh [open "the_file_contain_path" "r"]

while {![eof $fh]} { 
  set line [gets $fh]
  if {[regexp -- {\$\S+} $line]} {
    catch {exec /usr/local/bin/tcsh -c "echo  $line" } line
      if {![file exists $line]} {
        puts "ERROR: the file $line is not exists"
      }
  }
}
```

I sure there is more elegant solution without using

*/usr/local/bin/tcsh* -*c*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the variable name in the regexp command and do a lookup in Tcl's global `env` array. Also, your use of `eof` as the while condition means your loop will interate one time too many (see http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html#eof)

```
set fh [open "the_file_contain_path" "r"]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} { 
  # this can handle "$FOO/bar/$BAZ"
  if {[string first {$} $line] != -1} {
    regsub -all {(\$)(\w+)} $line {\1::env(\2)} new
    set line [subst -nocommand -nobackslashes $new]
  }

  if {![file exists $line]} {
    puts "ERROR: the file $line does not exist"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite the same thing; it doesn't handle `$FOO/bar` well.

Comment: Hello Glenn, your updated solution works right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's usually easier (for small files, say of no more than 1–2MB) to read in the whole file and `split` it into lines instead of using `gets` and `eof` in a `while` loop. (The `split` command is very fast.)

Secondly, to do the replacement you need the place in the string to replace, so you use `regexp -indices`. That does mean that you need to take a little more complex approach to doing the replacement, with `string range` and `string replace` to do some of the work. Assuming you're using Tcl 8.5…

```
set fh [open "the_file_contain_path" "r"]

foreach line [split [read $fh] "\n"] {
    # Find a replacement while there are any to do
    while {[regexp -indices {\$(\w+)} $line matchRange nameRange]} {

        # Get what to replace with (without any errors, just like tcsh)
        set replacement {}
        catch {set replacement $::env([string range $line {*}$nameRange])}

        # Do the replacement
        set line [string replace $line {*}$matchRange $replacement]
    }

    # Your test on the result
    if {![file exists $line]} {
        puts "ERROR: the file $line is not exists"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TCL programs can read environment variables using the built-in global variable `env`. Read the line, look for `$` followed by a name, look up `$::env($name)`, and substitute it for the variable.

Using the shell for this is very bad if the file is supplied by untrusted users. What if they put `; rm *` in the file? And if you're going to use a shell, you should at least use sh or bash, not tcsh.